# scrapy.Request doesn't enter the download middleware, it returns Request instead of response

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using scrapy.Spider to **scrape**, and I want to use request inside my callback function which is in start_requests, but that request didn't work, it should return a response but it only returns Request.

I followed the debug breakpoint and found that in class Request(object_ref), the request only finished the initialization but it didn't go into  request = next(slot.start_requests) as expected, to start requesting, thus only returning Request.

Here is my code in brief:

```py
class ProjSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Proj'
    allowed_domains = ['mashable.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        # pages
        pages = 10
        for i in range(1, pages):
            url = "https://mashable.com/channeldatafeed/Tech/new/page/"+str(i)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_mashable)
```

Request works fine yet
and following is:

```py
    def parse_mashable(self, response):
        item = Item()
        json2parse = response.text
        json_response = json.loads(json2parse)
        d = json_response['dataFeed'] # a list containing dicts, in which there is url for detailed article
        for data in d:
            item_url = data['url'] # the url for detailed article
            item_response = self.get_response_mashable(item_url)
            # here I want to parse the item_response to get detail
            item['content'] = item_response.xpath("//body").get
            yield item

    def get_response_mashable(self,url):
        response = scrapy.Request(url) 
        # using self.parser. I've also defined my own parser and yield an item
        # but the problem is it never got to callback
        return response # tried yield also but failed
```

this is where Request doesn't work. The url is in the allowed_domains, and it's not a duplicate url. I'm guessing it's because of scrapy's asynchronous mechanism of Request, but how could it affect the request in self.parse_mashable, by then the Request in start_requests is already finished.
I managed to do the second request in python Requests-html, but still I couldn't figure out why.

So could anyone help pointing where I'm doing wrong? Thx in advance!

Comment: Why are you calling `yield` in `parse_mashable()`?  Yield works with loops, but that function does not have a loop.

Comment: thx for pointing out it! Since return doesn't work I just tried yield (I think maybe yield can make scrapy to schedule this request) and create a loop behind which doesn't work..

Comment: The callback function `parse_mashable()` returns a value, but I'm not sure scrapy supports that.  Where are you expecting this returned value to go?

Comment: Oh sorry I gotta edit my code to make it clearer. I expect parse_mashable() to yield an item, of which the fileds I've defined in item.py, and in pipelines.py I get item to go into a mongodb. So far with requests-html to make request I can get it to work,  but it's not fast.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my question.  When parse_mashable returns returns `item`, where do you expect item to be used?  What piece of code actually _accepts_ that value from the callback?

Comment: I defined a `MongoPipeline` class, which is basically the same as in the official docs and it worked, so I don't bother to write it out. In MongoPipeline, there is `process_item(self, item, spider):`, it accepts item and insert it into mongodb. But I think the problem is not about item here, since when I use requests-html the item can be inserted, but with scrapy.Request there is no response.

Comment: Can you please add documentation for your function? Because not fully understand why need `get_response_mashable` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy doesn't really expect you to do this the way you're trying to, so it doesn't have a simple way to do it.

What you should be doing instead is passing the data you've scraped from the original page to the new callback using the request's `meta` dict.

For details, check [Passing additional data to callback functions](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments).